# Format of the "maxRunningTime" option (Google AI Platform)

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, gcp-ai-platform-training

I want to run my ML training jobs at Google AI platform with a specific time limit. In the [API documentation](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/ml/v1/python/latest/ml_v1.projects.jobs.html#create) there is an option `maxRunningTime`, however there is no indication of the format anywhere. I've tried several variants and I get different errors, e.g.:

For `t60s`: `Invalid duration format, failed to parse seconds`

For `60m` or `60`: `Illegal duration format; duration must end with 's'`

For `60s`: `Request contains an invalid argument.`

Is there a way to pass this argument when creating a job?

Comment: I think the format `60s` is correct, but the value is too small. Try `86400s` to verify. I don't know what this lower limit is.

Comment: @JohnHanley I've tried larger values as well, they fail with the same error. I have a feeling they deprecated this option, as it is not to be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/reference/rest/v1/projects.jobs#TrainingInput), but that is a weird way to do it (without updating python API and also throwing inconsistent errors).